# Como obtener el tiempo de respuesta al toque de mi movil y usarlo como variable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, depuración

Estoy haciendo una app al estilo Human Benchamark que tienes que pulsar la pantalla lo mas rapido que puedas despues de un estimulo visual.
Pero esta marca de mas dado que el movil tiene cierto retardo.

Ya estuve buscando informacion pero no encuentro la forma de conocer el lag que suma mi movil a la respuesta de mi app para poder restarlo al resultado para que sea mas correcto (hablo de ms).

La aplicacion la desarrollo en flutter y VS code, busco alguna opcion del debugger, plugin o comando.

A pesar de esto,
La mejor solucion para mi problema sería : algun widget para obtener la latencia y alamacenarla en una variable para luego usarla.

Mi aplicación consiste en que ante un estimulo visual se haga tap en la pantalla obteniendo el tiempo de reaccion(reflejos), y mi intencion es que dado que existe una latencia, querria conocerla para poder restar esos milisegundos de latencia a mi resultado final para que sea mas veraz.

Todo esto en un dispositivo movil fisico.

**Aclaracion funcionamiento**:

En mi apliación inicialmente tienes una pantalla en un color (rojo) y depsues de un tiempo aleatorio cambia a verde y tienes que hacer tap lo mas rapido posible , devolviendote el tiemo en ms o s que tardaste, intentando reflejar tu tiempo de reaccion humano, esto todo lo hago con un patron BLoC, estados(por los que va pasando la pantalla para que asi sea mas ligero) y un StopWatch, obviamente estoy siendo muy breve con todo.

Gracias.

Adjunto codigo: [Link a Github](https://github.com/jmlgomez73/Reactions)

Comment: si tiene latencia es por el dispositivo o flutter, prueba en un telf fisico, en react hay latencia por que se ejecuta en un hilo diferente y no el UIthread. No se si sera lo mismo en flutter, averigua. Si se basa en graficos usa open gl para usar la gpu.

Comment: lo he probado en un dispositivo fisico , osea en todo momneto me he referido a al tiempo de retardo entre un evento en una app y la respuesta de la app

Comment: ¿En qué consiste el "estimulo visual" y cómo lo implementas?

Comment: La aplicacion consiste en que inicialmente tienes una pantalla en un color (rojo) y depsues de un tiempo aleatorio cambia a verde y tienes que hacer tap lo mas rapido posible , devolviendote el tiemo en ms o s que tardaste, intentando reflejar tu tiempo de reaccion humano, esto todo lo hago con un patron BLoC, estados(por los que va pasando la pantalla para que asi sea mas ligero) y un StopWatch, obviamente estoy siendo muy breve con todo.

Comment: El tiempo de retardo de un evento y la app no existe casi sera 5ms creo o menos, El perfomance de como lo estes haciendo es la cosa, mas que seguro flutter usa un hilo en background igual que react native.  Hazlo nativo abres la imagen haces correr el tiempo y pausas tras que apreta,

Comment: La verdad no se como hacer lo que me pides de hacerla nativa, de todas formas suponiendo que el problema se oculte en la performance de la app, habria alguna aplicacion o comando para averiguar los tiempos (ms) uqe tarda de hacer una cosa a otra para poder sustraer dicho "tiempo de procesamiento" a mi resultado final, para buscar mas veracidad en lo que mi aplicacion intenta averguar?, Gracias.

Comment: La única manera que veo es que cuentes cuánto tiempo pasa desde que se ejecuta el código de "cambiar de color" hasta que termina de ejecutarse

Comment: sugerencia de que usar? por que eso mismo que me cuentas creo que es lo que hago ya como finalidad de mi app , por que ese tiempo entre cambio de pantalla y el tap del usario es el tiempo de reaccion , uso un Stopwatch para ello

Comment: no entiendo, porque simplemente cuando el color cambia (sin animación), no guardas el tiempo inicial en una variable para luego cuando el usuario da tap, obtienes el tiempo actual y restas con el que tenías para que veas cuanto demoró.

Comment: eso ya lo hago , precisamente esa es la vairbale que devuelvo como resultado del tiempo de reaccion del usuario , pero este tiempo no es el que deberia, bajo mi criterio afecta el tiempo de ejecucion del programa,,, por ejemplo de media el resultado deberia ser unos 250ms pero se muestran unos 4xx ms , como es variable no puedo concretar en un numero que restarle a mi resultado final para que sea veraz, y esa numero es el que quiero averiguar, He adjuntado el codigo, está comentado